# Why Categories are working but subcategories are not

Tags: category, issue

I've been facing an issue lately where the latest subcategories fail to work unless I either use the URL like this

https://www.jadeed.store/categories/personal-care.html?cat=277_mini-fans

For this: https://www.jadeed.store/categories/personal-care/mini-fans.html (doesn't work)

or I turn it into a main category where it works immediately (e.g.https://www.jadeed.store/categories/mini-fan-2.html and for a while when i put it back into sub category mode before it fails again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path `categories/personal-care/mini-fans.html` into URL re-writes list.

> Path : Admin -> Marketing -> URL Rewrites

Find in Request path column.

If not found then create url for this category

Comment: I didn't get that fully. Where should i look in magento 2?

Comment: URL have been created but they're not responding if its become a sub-category within minutes

Comment: This issue only persists with newly made subcategories. Otherwise existing old ones are working find

Comment: After admin login : 

    : Admin -> Marketing -> URL Rewrites

Comment: Checked there. Nothing there worked.

Comment: You need to generate the url for the same

Comment: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was a URL issue but not in the way I expected it: The version of Magento I use was using some old category and subcategory URL's that I changed that got stuck on their old version. The using those URLs solved the problems I was dealing with.